# using awk for subsetting fastq file based on length of sequence

Tags: awk

I have a fastq file. I will explain what it is. It is something like this

```
@SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
GATACAGGATGCCTGGGTCTAGGCTGTGTGACCTTGGGCCAGTTCCTCTC
+SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
DDDFFDDBGFEHEHGIGC9F>HG9EH8?DF4?:DF<?3:D?DHIGGDDFH
@SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
CTGCTGCTCATGCTCAT
+SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
BDDDDD<<CC:C+AFFE
@SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
AGCGTGTGCCACCCTACGCCGGC
+SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
DD>DAA@AA@@?2C8AB)?@:DD
@SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
AGACAGAAGGGGAGTACAGCTCTCTGGAACATGAGAGTGCAAGGGGTTGAGTGTTT
+SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
DDDFFFCFGEHI@CGFADFGCCFFGHFGCFFFHGGDGHIFHDFGGI<BF=DHIHHH
```

Now 4 lines correspond to 1 read so

```
@SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
GATACAGGATGCCTGGGTCTAGGCTGTGTGACCTTGGGCCAGTTCCTCTC
+SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
DDDFFDDBGFEHEHGIGC9F>HG9EH8?DF4?:DF<?3:D?DHIGGDDFH
```

corresponds to 1 read which is **GATACAGGATGCCTGGGTCTAGGCTGTGTGACCTTGGGCCAGTTCCTCTC**

I showed you the fastq file above. What i want to do is I want to extract only those reads in which length of the read seq is <= 25, So my output should be

```
@SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
CTGCTGCTCATGCTCAT
+SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
BDDDDD<<CC:C+AFFE
@SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
AGCGTGTGCCACCCTACGCCGGC
+SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
DD>DAA@AA@@?2C8AB)?@:DD
```

I want to use awk for this purpose.

I tried something like this

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {if(length($1) <= 25) print $0}; NR % 2 == 1' test.fastq
```

BUT this prints something like this

```
@SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
+SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
@SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
CTGCTGCTCATGCTCAT
+SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
BDDDDD<<CC:C+AFFE
@SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
AGCGTGTGCCACCCTACGCCGGC
+SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
DD>DAA@AA@@?2C8AB)?@:DD
@SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
+SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
```

Clearly I don't want

```
@SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
+SRR1024120.7 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1386:1189 length=100
@SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
+SRR1024120.1 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1200:1120 length=100
```

in my output.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use record and field separators to stop awk from using the newlines and spaces.  Instead, you can use "\n@" to show record separation, and a plain "\n" to separate the fields.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n@";FS="\n"} {if (length($2) <= 25) {print "@"$0} }' fastq
@SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
CTGCTGCTCATGCTCAT
+SRR1024120.25 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:1752:1149 length=100
BDDDDD<<CC:C+AFFE
@SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
AGCGTGTGCCACCCTACGCCGGC
+SRR1024120.42 DBRHHJN1:259:D0PM7ACXX:1:1101:2482:1096 length=100
DD>DAA@AA@@?2C8AB)?@:DD
```

Each of the lines will be a different field, so you can check that second line's length with $2.  I had to add the "@" back in when printing, since it gets eaten by the record separator.

Comment: The answer is nice but some times 4th line has @ at the begining. So it is creating a problem. Any solution for it??

Comment: What exactly separates new records?  Are they always 4 rows?  Is it a specific pattern at the beginning of the first line or the end of the last?